# Integrate SonarQube with Jenkins

Tags: scala, jenkins, sonarqube, sbt, code-analysis

How to Integrate Sonarqube 5.4 with jenkins for Scala code analysis? I have seen third part plugins like:

```
github.com/Sagacify/sonar-scala , 
github.com/RadoBuransky/sonar-scoverage-plugin ,
github.com/ncredinburgh/sonar-scalastyle ,
github.com/scoverage/scalac-scoverage-plugin ,
```

but they don't seem to work.

Is there any other way for Scala analysis? By default sonarqube does Java analysis. I want Scala code analysis.

Comment: Are you getting an error message?

Comment: Yes, ERROR: You must install a plugin that supports the language 'scala'
ERROR: 
ERROR: Re-run SonarQube Scanner using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
ERROR: SonarQube scanner exited with non-zero code: 1